# nodejs - mocking modules, naive approach

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking

Currently I am writing some unit tests for my server side code that is written using `nodejs`.

Now, I have a situation where my custom module is using some other modules, mine or from `nodejs` standard library and I wanted to mock them. Firstly I googled around for some existing solutions, for example I found: https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire and https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery.

But today I tried to use naive approach and do something like this: `moduleUnderTest`

```
var fs = require('fs');
exports.foo = function(){
  console.log("===foo===");
  fs.read();
}
```

and file `moduleUnderTestSpec`:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var moduleUnderTests = require('../server/moduleUnderTests.js');

fs.read = function(){
  console.log("===read===");
}
```

and when I run `grunt jasmine_node` I can see:

```
===foo===
===read===
```

so in this simple case I could swap one of the functions in `fs` module for other one. Is there any situations where my approach will not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First take a look at [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) as it will help you mock or stub out functions easily.

When you `require` a module in Node.js the modules are cached according to [docs on modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching).

The only problem I see with your solution is that later if you need to use the real `fs.read` you won't be able to as it's lost. For example you can use Sinon like so;

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sinon = require('sinon');

// mock fs.read
sinon
  .stub(fs, 'read')
  .returns("string data");

// test your code that uses fs.read
assert(fs.read.calledOnce);

// then restore
fs.read.restore();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is ok, but it will work only if module exports object. If a module exports function (which happens a lot) or anything else, you can't mock it. That is, you can mock only a property of module object, but not the whole object.

Comment: Oops wrong link to the wrong mockery. It should have been https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery